# JQuery IFrame Load event firing too soon

Tags: jquery, events, iframe, browser-history

I have tried in vain to find a solution for this issue, but to no avail. Basically I am trying use JQuery to create a new dialog when a button on the page is clicked. The content of the dialog contains an IFrame referencing external (cross-domain) content. Inside the dialog I also want a "back" link (will change to a button later on) that acts similar to the browsers back button. Granted I could just get the user to use the normal back button, but this isn't really all that intuitive hence I want the back button simply inside the dialog itself above the iframe.

The javascript for this is relatively simple using the "history" object. However, I want the ability to disable / remove this "back" link when the history count exceeds a certain level. The details of the disabling functionality are trivial enough, however I need to be able to access the load event of the iframe to determine when the content has finished loading so that the history.length value will be correct for the purposes of my test. However the load event seems to be fired too soon and the history value is not correct at the time the load event is fired. The history value appears to be correct when going "forwards" but after clicking my impromtu back button, the history value is no longer correct as it appears the load event is reporting a history value *prior* to the iframe having loaded the content.

Here is my current javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var baseHistory = 0;

$(function() {
  $("body").append('<div id="RedmapDialog" title="Dialog Title"></div>');
  $(".RedmapButton").bind('click', function(event) {
    baseHistory = history.length;
    var data='<a href = "javascript:history.go(-1)">Back to previous page</a>'
    data = data + '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="RMFrame"></iframe>'
    $("#RedmapDialog").html(data);
    $("#RedmapDialog").dialog("option", "title", 'Document: ');
    $("#RedmapDialog").dialog("open");
    $('#RMFrame').load(function() {
      alert("history.length=" + history.length);
    }).attr("src", "http://www.google.com/");
  });

  $("#RedmapDialog").dialog({  
    closeOnEscape: false,    
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    autoOpen: false,    
    resizable: true,
    autoResize:true,
    modal: false           
  });  
});

</script>
```

and here is the calling html:

```
<div class="RedmapButton" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;">
  <img src="/gui/images/bullseye.gif" width=26 height=26 alt="Redmap" title="Redmap">
</div>
```

Any thought's as to why the load event is being called so soon after I select my back link? I understand that there are some cross-domain / same origin policy issues at play here, however I am not interested in the actual content of the iframe, simply the history.length value only.

Edit: Updated this post to include a suggestion by ShankarSangoli for setting the src of my iframe after its instantiation. However, I am still encountering the original issue whereby my "back" link still reports an incorrect history.length. Here is a jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/fEgv9/1 that illustrates my issue. When run, click the "Redmap" image to display the iframe. Then click any link from google, and then hit my "Back to previous page" link, note that the history is not reporting correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are setting the source of the `iframe` when you added markup to `RedmapDialog` and after that load event handler is attached. Before it reaches this code the iframe must have already been loaded. Try to set the source of the iframe after you have set the iframe load event handler as below

```
$(".RedmapButton").bind('click', function(event) {
    baseHistory = history.length;
    var data='<a href = "javascript:history.go(-1)">Back to previous page</a>'
    data = data + '<iframe src="javascript:void(0);" width="100%" height="100%" id="RMFrame"></iframe>'
    $("#RedmapDialog").html(data);
    $("#RedmapDialog").dialog("option", "title", 'Document: ');
    $("#RedmapDialog").dialog("open");
    $('#RMFrame').load(function() {
      alert("history.length=" + history.length);
    }).attr("src", "http://www.google.com/");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, yes I tried your technique above, and yes the load function does output my alert. However once again, after selecting my "Back to previous page" link, the history.length has incremented the counter. Here is a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fEgv9/1/ that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I see the history.length is 1 in the fiddle.

Comment: But I have answered your question.

Comment: Is the history.length 1 *after* clicking my Back to Previous page link? I guess what I'm getting at is that I would like to see the history count increment as I navigate through pages, and decrement as the back link is used.

Comment: I am seeing it as 1 after click on the link. I think you should open a new question for that.

Comment: The basis of my question is in fact the increment and decrement of this history counter. Perhaps I phrased my quesiton incorrectly if you think it needs further clarification. In effect, your solution of appending the src after defining the frame itself had no difference in effect to my simply invoking the load() event that I originally had.

Comment: If you think this answer has helped you please accept it, thanks

Comment: I don't think it helped me, hence I wasn't going to accept it. Although I do definitely appreciate your efforts!

Comment: I think the problem is with fiddle since it uses iframe, may be because of that the history.length is not coming up fine. Can you try this code in your application directly instead of fiddle.

Comment: Anyways I enjoyed helping you with whatever knowledge I have

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating the iframe with jquery, then attaching the ready (not load) event to the created frame, assigning the src attribute and finally appending the element to your div. The code would go something like this:

```
$("<iframe />").ready(function(){ alert(this.location); }) //Use your function here
  .attr("src","www.slashdot.com")
  .appendTo(document.body); //Append to your div
```

The thing about ready and load on iframes is that load is triggered when the DOMFrame element is created and attached to the DOM tree (regardless of it's internal state), while ready does wait for the internal state of the iframe.

Comment: Hrm, I just tried your solution, and the issue I have is that the ready function only gets called once, I need my function to be called every time the user clicks a link contained by the iframe source so that I can track the history count. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, I think I've stumbled upon a similar problem before. For what I recall, I used a $.Deferred() instead of directly using the ready method of the iframe. Basically I used something like this:

`var dfr = $.Deferred();`
`$("<iframe />").ready(function(){ dfr.resolve(); }).[...]`
`dfr.done(function(){ /* your code here */ });`